SQLAlchemy AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'connect'
I'm trying to populate a database with Python and SQLAlchemy using the same syntax as I've used in previous projects, but now I'm getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/populate_db.py", line 16, in <module>
    with Session(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URI'), future=True) as session, session.begin():
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/util.py", line 147, in __exit__
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/util.py", line 145, in __exit__
    self.commit()
  File "<string>", line 2, in commit
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1313, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "<string>", line 2, in _prepare_impl
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1288, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4352, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4487, in _flush
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4448, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 466, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 642, in execute
    util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 60, in save_obj
    for (
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 223, in _organize_states_for_save
    for state, dict_, mapper, connection in _connections_for_states(
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1753, in _connections_for_states
    connection = uowtransaction.transaction.connection(base_mapper)
  File "<string>", line 2, in connection
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1039, in connection
    return self._connection_for_bind(bind, execution_options)
  File "<string>", line 2, in _connection_for_bind
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1175, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = self._parent._connection_for_bind(
  File "<string>", line 2, in _connection_for_bind
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
  File "/home/vacosti/scraper_v2/svenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1189, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = bind.connect()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'connect'

My table definition is the following:
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float, LargeBinary
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Product(Base):  # type: ignore
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) #as per the docs The default value is the string "auto", which indicates that a single-column (i.e. non-composite) primary key that is of an INTEGER type with no other client-side or server-side default constructs indicated should receive auto increment semantics automatically.
    external_id = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)
    udescription = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)
    price = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    image = Column(LargeBinary)



My code to populate the database is the following:
import os
import json
import codecs
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from database.tables import Product

from pathlib import Path
CURRENT_DIR = Path(__file__).parent

products = json.loads(codecs.open(os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR,'data/products.json')).read())

for product in products:
    with Session(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URI'), future=True) as session, session.begin():
        productORM = Product(external_id=product['product_id'], description=product['description'], udescription=product['udescription'], price=product['price'])
        session.add(productORM)

About the syntax with Session(...) as session, session.begin():, the docs says I can do so.
What could be the problem in this case?

just reading the docs, i don't know sqlalchemy. it says that the first argument of Session should be an engine, but you provided a string instead

and i think you should open the session and do your loop inside instead of opening multiple sessions

You are absolutely right. Such a silly mistake. Thank you very much. I think I will update the question.

In SQLAlchemy Sessions accept engine objects. You should use create_engine, which accepts database uri that you can pass with environs.
There are other minor mistakes:

(As pointed out by folen gateis) You might want to move the with Session out of the for-loop to avoid frequent Session creation (frequent connecting to database which is slow)

Maybe you need to read the quickstart part thoroughly before actually starting with your project. It won't take long.

the commit is already managed by the context manager (with)

@folengateis Could you please tell me which part of the docs or codes stated that sqlalchemy Sessions automatically commit after context manager? All examples with with Session comes with commit, didn't find the doc mentioning auto-commit features, and __exit__ only contains a self.close call. And there are cases where you have to rollback instead of commit.

you should take a good hard look at the link provided by op

@folengateis ok I overlooked the .begin() part, my bad. Answer edited
